# My Flutter App gets a grey Screen when i build in Relase Mode

Tags: flutter, dart, build

When I build my Flutter app in release mode, these two gray boxes appear:

[App Screenshot][1]

The upper box
Contains this build code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return  Expanded(

    child: Row(

  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  children:<Widget> [


  ValueListenableBuilder(valueListenable:placeNotify ,builder: (context,value,child){
          return Text(value.toString(),textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight:FontWeight.w300,color: Colors.black45));
        },)

  ],
    ),

        );


// TODO: implement build
throw UnimplementedError();
```

}

The bottom box
Contains this build code:I only show the top part is a lot of code

```
return Expanded(

  child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: <Widget>[


        Flexible(
            flex: 2,

            child: Column(

                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[


                  Directionality(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    child: DropShadow(
                      blurRadius: 10,

                      offset: const Offset(3, 3),
                      spread: 1,
                      child: Flexible(
                        flex: 2,

                        child: Container(
                          width: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.orange[200],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            gradient: const LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                Color(0xFFEC3DEC),
                                Color(0xFF73C5ED)
                              ],
                            ),
```

The Main Build look like this:

```
 return  Container( child:Column(

    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children:<Widget> [

      SizedBox(height: 50),
      Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange[200],
                border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black45)
            ),
            child: getPositionAdress()
        )
      ),

      Flexible(
        flex: 2,
        child:Container(color: Colors.cyan[100],
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Wetteddaten(),

      ) ,
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 2,
        child:MaterialApp(color: Colors.blue,
          title: 'Flutter Google Maps Demo',
          home: MapSample(),

        ),
      ),
```

This problem is already known in a modified form. Can someone explain to me the basic procedure for avoiding this problem?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UTh7.png

Comment: when you run in debug mode do you see any errors in the terminal?

Comment: Check for null values on the getPositionAddress() and Wettedaten() its just might the data  is not there.

Comment: getPosition and WeatherData works in Debug Mode
What do you mean by checking for null values?                                                           
  In terminal only print this error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: TimeoutException after 0:00:02.000000: Future not completed

And these components prints "bottom overflowed by pixel".
This i have i solved by changing the size.

Comment: Never use Expanded or Flexible as ParentWidget.
Every widget produced wants to use the space it already has.
Only use expansion widgets when you want to manage the space in a Column which is under the widget tree.

Comment: This is the reason for the error you are getting now.
Reconsider the places where you used Expanded.

Comment: The reason for the gray screen is that in debug mode the red screen appears but in release mode these are grayed out

Comment: Now i have solved it changed to Container.  but 
Now I seem to have another problem with the permissions Geolocation not working must i Add a new Question ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of expanded widget, you can use Flexible widget instead

```
Flexible(
 fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: ...,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Expanded widget and the green screen will be gone